# How to select div with id nested in another div with class in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two nested div elements. The outer one has a clas and the nested one has an id. How can I select the nested div using its parent?

example:

```
<div class="parent-class">
  <div id="body">
  </div>
</div>
```

so, I was wondering how to select #body using its parent .parent-class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other equally valid options include:

```
.parent-class #body {ruleset here}
div.parent-class #body {ruleset here}
.parent-class div#body {ruleset here}
div.parent-class div#body {ruleset here}
.parent-class > div {ruleset here}
```

The possibilities go on and on frankly.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: `.parent-class div {ruleset here}`

Comment: This isn't 100% correct.  This would select every `div` element that falls as a child of `.parent-class`.  So, although it would select `#body` in the example markup posted, it would also select any other `div` children of `.parent-class`, or any `div` children of `#body`, or of `#body`'s siblings..

Comment: @johnkavanagh Of course, I gave an answer to this question. In fact, if we were talking globally, there's no need to specify a parent class/id of an element whose id we know, right?

Comment: that's absolutely correct!  Although, there is a chance that the sort of specificity where an `#ID` is selected from a parent `class` would still be needed.  If a CSS file is used on every page on a site, then the same ID could potentially be reused in different situations.. It's a bit of a minefield really!

Comment: @johnkavanagh Great thinking! Not sure if that's a proper use of IDs, but definitely a possible scenario.

Comment: I don't think it would be an incorrect use of IDs to be honest.  IDs are simply unique to that specific page (in the case of HTML) so there's nothing to dictate parents/positions within the page.  It's something I've come across before when sites get large and there are different page templates.  Both answers are correct, I gather the OP is a learner at the moment so it's good to give all the different options and explanations.

Comment: @johnkavanagh I agree. I didn't mean it's incorrect, but maybe "not ideal". :)

Answer (score 4):

As simple as:

```css
.parent-class #body{
    /* styles here */
}
```

However, as has been pointed out in a comment to this answer: you don't necessarily need to use inheritance in this way as an ID should be unique on each page, so this would be just as relevant at targeting that second element:

```css
#body{
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: No point doing it with an id specified since ids are supposed to be unique on the page and it's not what OP asked for...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent-class > div {}`

OR

Since IDs must be unique, you only need: `#body{}`